# Python, Selenium... not able to find an element which is obviously there

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, authentication, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to use Python (Selenium) to extract data from this site:
https://sin.clarksons.net/

After I put in user name and password, it is not able to click the obvious "Submit" bottom. Can some of you help to see why? TIA.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        chrome_path = r"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
        driver.get("https://www.clarksons.net/")
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(5)

        login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu"]/li[1]/span')
        time.sleep(5)
        login.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="usernameText"]')
        username.clear()
        username.send_keys("abc(at)hotmail.com")

        password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/input[1]')
        password.clear()
        password.send_keys("xyzabc")

        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div/div/button')
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print "login"
        driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: put `time.sleep(5)` before you click button. if this works you should change it to explicit wait.  Also verify your xpath, it's very long, use id or name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replace xpath with id and use css selector for login button

```
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("usernameText")
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("vivi.sandsten@gard.no")

    password = driver.find_element_by_id("passwordText")
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("xyzabc")

    #submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@title='Login']")
    submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#home button.btn-
    primary")
    submit.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the login button by title:

```
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@title, "Login")]')
submit.click()
```

OR You can find the form and then submit (find base on class):

```
submit_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[starts-with(@class, "ng-valid ng-dirty")]')
submit_form .submit()
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! Anywhere I can find a good tutorial on this?

Comment: For me, learning this I just google for xpath to select by class, title, text etc... Selenium support 3 ways to select html element (just like anything out there), find element by id, by css and xpath, the performance decline in order, but if you work with small test, and dont need high performance then i suggest stuck with xpath (ID can be used in some case, which is obvious).

Answer (score 0):

The `xpath` you are using is wrong, the correct one is

```
'/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button'
```

As a side note, you really shouldn't use absolute `xpath`, for example you can use `'//button[@title="Login"]'` for the login button.

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved. Coud you tell me a bit more why not to used absolute xpath? or maybe refer to some online resource discussing what to use? I am actually new to selenium and do not know well about how to locating items...

Comment: @user3918496 There are several reasons not to use absolute `xpath`. Performance (much slower than relative `xpath` or methods like `find_element_by_id`), readability and fragility (imagine someone add a `<div>` tag before the `<form>`. Absolute `xpath` will fail, relative will still work).